# SwipeRefreshLayout Limit to Top Half only

Tags: java, android

I managed to load a webview in a swiperefreshlayout wrapper however the first part of my webview is a scrollable up/down html div. So when scrolling down on it, the swipe refresh layout kicks in instead. Can I limit my swipe refresh layout only to the first quarter of the screen?

Thanks

Comment: I mean add some code, this it too broad.

Answer (score 0):

First for all, you need to broadcast scrolling changes in WebView. For ex. by using extension for it with callback and notify about changes updates.

```
public class ObservableWebView extends WebView
{
    private OnScrollChangedCallback mOnScrollChangedCallback;

    public ObservableWebView(final Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public ObservableWebView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ObservableWebView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(final int l, final int t, final int oldl, final int oldt)
    {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        if(mOnScrollChangedCallback != null) mOnScrollChangedCallback.onScroll(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    }

    public OnScrollChangedCallback getOnScrollChangedCallback()
    {
        return mOnScrollChangedCallback;
    }

    public void setOnScrollChangedCallback(final OnScrollChangedCallback onScrollChangedCallback)
    {
        mOnScrollChangedCallback = onScrollChangedCallback;
    }

    /**
     * Implement in the activity/fragment/view that you want to listen to the webview
     */
    public static interface OnScrollChangedCallback
    {
        public void onScroll(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt);
    }
}
```

And then, just listen the changes, for certain threshold, to enable disable `SwipeToRefreshLayout`. Like in sample below.

```
wv = (ObservableWebView) findViewById(R.id.scorllableWebview);
wv.setOnScrollChangedCallback(new OnScrollChangedCallback() {

    public void onScroll(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {

        if (t> oldt) {
            Timber.d("Swipe UP");
            // Check if it's top page, knowing height of the items
            // and enable swipe to refresh
            swipeToRefresh.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else if (t< oldt) {
            Timber.d("Swipe Down");
            // Again if scrolled enough to bottom, disable again
            swipeToRefresh.setEnabled(false);
        }
        Timber.d("Scrolling....");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @GensaGames, I added the setOnScrollChangedCallback to the MainActivity java file, but where should I add the ObservableWebView class ? In the same folder as the MainActivity?